# DataTables does not display the data

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

DataTables does not work when it runs the page **data.php**. The json code runs perfectly, but I do not get the data in the jQuery ajax DataTables function.

When I run the **index.php** page, it gives a message in table: 'No data available in table'.

index.php (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax":{
      "url":"data.php",
      "dataSrc":""
    },
    "columns": [
      { "data": "id" },
      { "data": "city" },
      { "data": "country" }
    ]
  });
});
```

data.php(ajax url)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "aaa";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, city, country FROM order_product";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows=array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[]=$row;
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($rows);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I suggest you to post a sample of the data returned by `data.php`.